# Build with Jekyll failed because of unknown tag

Tags: github, jekyll, github-actions

I fork a blog repository on Github with JekylI and push my article to the `_post` folder.
I attached the macro code for Jinja2 to the article as below

```
{% macro -%}
```

However the github actions "pages build and deployment" is failed because of the build stage threw an exception

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 69): Unknown tag 'macro' in
```

I tried to increment "\" before "%" like this and Jekyll build success

```
{\% macro -\%}
```

But "\" is also displayed in the article

I also tried to fork other Jekyll repository, the phenomenon is the same, so I think it is jekyll build problem

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `{}` in the code are identified by Jekyll as Liquid code.
Add `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` to tell Jekyll not to treat the content as Liquid code

```
{% raw %}
{% macro -%}
{% endraw %}
```